# TypeError: updatedService.save is not a function when using testing NestJS API with Jests and Mongoose

Tags: mongoose, jestjs, nestjs

Depending on the user input DTO, A product's information can be Updated using `HTTP PATCH`. My NestJS Service is as follows:

```js
async updateAProduct(product: ProductDTO ) {
        const updatedProduct = await this.findProduct(product.id);
        if (product.title) {
            updatedProduct.title = product.title;
        }
        if (product.description) {
            updatedProduct.description = product.description;
        }
        if (product.price) {
            updatedProduct.price = product.price;
        }
        updatedProduct.save()
    }
```

Where `ProductDTO` is an interface:

```js
export interface ProductDTO {
    id?: string;
    title?: string;
    description?: string;
    price?: number;
}
```

The  `updatedProduct` is a Mongoose Document (`ProductDoc`) returned from `findProduct`:

```js
import { Document } from 'mongoose';

export interface ProductDoc extends Document {
    id: string;
    title: string;
    description: string;
    price: number;   
}
```

The `updateAProduct` service is called in a controller as follows:

```js
    @Patch('/update/:id')
    async updateAProduct(@Param('id') id: string, @Body() product: ProductDTO) {
        product.id = id;
        await this.productService.updateAProduct(product);
        return null;
    }
```

While writing `products.service.spec.ts` I wrote the following test:

```js
describe('ProductsService', () => {
  let service: ProductsService;
  let model: Model<ProductDoc>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        ProductsService,
        {
          provide: getModelToken('Product'),
          useValue: {
            new: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(mockProduct()),
            constructor: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(mockProduct()),
            findById: jest.fn(),
            find: jest.fn(),
            findOne: jest.fn(),
            update: jest.fn(),
            create: jest.fn(),
            remove: jest.fn(),
            exec: jest.fn(),
          },
        },
      ],
    }).compile();

    service = module.get<ProductsService>(ProductsService);
    model = module.get<Model<ProductDoc>>(getModelToken('Product'));
  });

  it('should update a product sucessfully', async() => {
    
    jest.spyOn(model, 'findById').mockReturnValue({
      exec: jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce(
        mockProductDoc({id: 'uuid1', title: 'Title1', description: 'Description1', price: 50.99})
      ),
    } as any);
    const updatedProduct = await service.updateAProduct({
      id: 'uuid1',
      title: 'New Title',
      price: 200.00
    });

    expect(updatedProduct).toEqual(mockProduct('uuid1', 'New Title', 'Description1',200.00));
  });
```

My Test fails as follows:

```sh
 FAIL  src/products/products.service.spec.ts (18.693s)
  ● ProductsService › should update a product sucessfully

    TypeError: updatedProduct.save is not a function

      49 |             updatedProduct.price = product.price;
      50 |         }
    > 51 |         updatedProduct.save()
         |                        ^
      52 |     }
      53 | 
      54 |     async deleteAProduct(prodID: string) {

      at ProductsService.updateAProduct (products/products.service.ts:51:24)
```

How do I overcome the unavailable `.save()` in the Jest test?

Sources:

1. I am just replicating the [Academind NestJS + MongoDB Tutorial](https://youtu.be/ulfU5vY6I78)
2. Since there a no tests in the tutorial I am completely relying on Repository Here [jmcdo29/testing-nestjs](https://github.com/jmcdo29/testing-nestjs)

#### EDIT

`findProduct` within the service

```js
  private async findProduct(productID: string): Promise<ProductDoc> {
        let product;
        try {
            product = await this.productModel.findById(productID).exec();
        } catch(error) {
            throw new NotFoundException('Could Not Find Product for given ID.');
        }
        if (!product) {
            throw new NotFoundException('Could Not Find Product for given ID.');
        }
        return product;
    }
```

Comment: your mocked `findProduct()` must return an object like `{...mockedObject, save: jest.fn()}`.  I hope you get the idea?!

Comment: Just realized it. I am trying it now.

Comment: @MoazzamArif Nope stil not working even though I added a `save: jest.fn()`

Comment: this should work, but how is `findProduct(product.id)` this implemented?

Comment: @MoazzamArif I have edited the question with the `findProduct`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My team faced the same error last month!

After searching for best practices, I found an easy way to do so...

I recommend using `*.repository.ts` files, so you could simply move all Mongoose stuff into that file, and leave your `*.service.spec.ts` much simpler and decoupled. So this error will never happen again.

Have a look at this example:

**product.repository.ts**

The idea is to place all Mongoose operations into the repository file, like update(), delete(), find(), populate(), aggregate(), save()...

```js
@Injectable()
export class ProductRepository {
    constructor(@InjectModel('Product') private readonly model: Model<Product>) {}

    async findProduct(id: string): Promise<Product> {
        return await this.model.findOne({_id: id}).exec();
    }

    async save(doc: any): Promise<Product> {
        return await new this.model(doc).save();
    }
}
```

**product.service.ts**

Don't use `@InjectModel` here instead inject the ProductRepository. Our service file should be as lean as possible and contain only business logic.

```js
@Injectable()
export class ProductService {
  constructor(private readonly repository: ProductRepository) {}

    async updateAProduct(product: ProductDTO) {
        const updatedProduct = await this.repository.findProduct(product.id);
        if (product.title) {
            updatedProduct.title = product.title;
        }
        if (product.description) {
            updatedProduct.description = product.description;
        }
        if (product.price) {
            updatedProduct.price = product.price;
        }
        await this.repository.save(updatedProduct);
    }
}
```

**product.module.ts**

Make sure you have `ProductRepository` in *providers*.

```js
@Module({
  imports: [MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'Product', schema: ProductSchema }])],
  controllers: [ProductController],
  providers: [ProductService, ProductRepository],
  exports: [ProductService],
})
export class ProductModule {}
```

**product.service.spec.ts**

** Instead of using `getModelToken('Product')` replace to `ProductRepository`.

```js
const mockProductRepository = {
    findProduct: jest.fn(),
    save: jest.fn(),
};

describe('ProductService', () => {
  let service: ProductService;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        ProductService,
        {
          provide: ProductRepository,
          useValue: mockProductRepository,
        }
      ],
    }).compile();

    service = module.get<ProductService>(ProductService);
  });

  describe('Update a product', () => {
    it('should update a product sucessfully', async () => {
        const findProductStub = {id: 'uuid1', title: 'Title1', description: 'Description1', price: 50.99};
        mockProductRepository.findProduct.mockResolvedValue(findProductStub);
        const saveProductStub = {id: 'uuid1', title: 'New Title', description: 'Description1', price: 200.00};
        mockProductRepository.save.mockResolvedValue(saveProductStub);
        const productToUpdateDto = {id: 'uuid1', title: 'New Title', description: 'Description1', price: 200.00};
        const result = await service.updateAProduct(productToUpdateDto);
        expect(result).toEqual({id: 'uuid1', title: 'New Title', description: 'Description1', price: 200.00});
    });
  });
});
```

Hope I could help you mate!

Comment: This was a great solution. Do you usually shift other Mongoose CRUD functions in the repository like `create()` and `find().exec()` ?

Comment: Yeah, the idea is to place all Mongoose operations into the repository file, like `updateOne()`, `deleteOne()`, `find()`, `findOne()`, `findById()`, `populate()`, `aggregate()`, `save()` and so on... Our service file should be as lean as possible and contain only business logic. Thanks mate!

Comment: I would suggest using `mockingoose` for mocking db CRUD. it will also keep mongoose schema while mocking return values